# Contar las veces que se envía un formulario (SOLO PHP)

Tags: php

necesito contar las veces que el usuario envía un formulario, he probado en crear una variable de sesión con el valor del botón envía, al principio si no esta creado lo crea y si ya esta le suma uno al contador.

```
//Contar preguntas
    $contadorPreguntas = 0;

if (!isset($_SESSION["enviar"])) {
        $_SESSION["enviar"] = $contadorPreguntas;
    } elseif (isset($_SESSION["enviar"])) {
        $contadorPreguntas++;
    }
```

Después muestro las preguntas que ha hecho así:

```
echo "Has hecho " .$contadorPreguntas ." preguntas";
```

Pero nunca pasa de 1. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

`$_SESSION["enviar"]` es la variable de sesión que se persiste entre peticiones.

`$contadorPreguntas` es una variable local que desaparecerá cuando termine la ejecución de la petición.

Tienes que obtener el valor de la variable en la sesión, y guardar en la sesión el nuevo valor.

```
$contadorPreguntas = $_SESSION["enviar"] + 1;
$_SESSION["enviar"] = $contadorPreguntas;
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Como indica @EduBw, si no tienes configurada la opción [`session.auto_start`](http://php.net/manual/es/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) a `true`, tienes que hacer [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) antes de empezar a trabajar con `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Acuérdate de abrir la sesion_start();